# How to order by in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-order-by, foreign-key-relationship

I'm working on a small blog engine.

There are the following tables: Blog and Message.

Blog has a foreign key: last_message_id, so I access the last message in the blog by calling blog.last_message

I have the following code to make it work:

```
class Blog < ActiveRecord::Base  
  belongs_to :last_message, :class_name => "Message"
end
```

I need to order the blogs by the last messages. But when I call

```
blogs.order("last_message.created_at DESC")
```

It doesn't work. I get the following error:

```
PGError: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "last_message"
ORDER BY  last_messa...
```

How can I make it work?

**UPDATE**

Here's the solution:

```
blogs.joins(:last_message).order("messages.created_at DESC").
```

Comment: what do you means by doesn't works ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your model is wrong. See rails automaticly add 2 attributes to a model : `created_at` and `update_at`. So having a relationship like you describe is redondant. To me, it should look like this :

```
#model/blog.rb
class Blog < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :messages
end

#model/message.rb
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :blog
end
```

Then, to get the blogs ordered by the last message, you could do this :

```
Blog.joins(:messages).order("messages.created_at_desc")
```

That as you may have noticed will give you double entries for your blog model. If that is not a problem, go ahead. If it is, you have two options : doing a `each` and test if you already saw the blog - if not, you display it. Or, you could write your own sql.

Comment: You missed the question. In Alex's datamodel he knows for each blog which the last-message is. Just to avoid this double messages problem.

Comment: I pointed that it's redondand with created_at - afterward, he does what he wants.

Comment: that's a good point. But the thing is, I already have the very some schema. Blog has_many :messages & Message belongs_to :blog. I also have the LAST_MESSAGE property, and that's where the problem is.

Comment: blogs.joins(:last_message).order("messages.created_at DESC").

Answer (score 1):

You have to make sure the last-messages are also selected to make that order-command work.\
So something like:

```
blogs.includes(:last_message).order("last_message.created_at desc")
```

Comment: I think you're in the right direction. However it still returns an error. I'll try to find more info about the "includes" method.