# sql query order problem

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, sqlite, activerecord

So I've got the follow model in activerecord, I will use `Discussion.user_replied_group_discussions(@user)`it returns the recent replied discussions alright, but how do I modify the private method to order the returned discussions by latest reply time?

```
# Table name: discussions
#
#  id               :integer         not null, primary key
#  title            :string(255)     not null
#  content          :text(255)       not null
#  created_at       :datetime
#  updated_at       :datetime
#  user_id          :integer
#  discussable_id   :integer
#  discussable_type :string(255)
class Discussion < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many    :comments, :as => :commentable, :dependent => :destroy
  #
  #this is the scope that I am having trouble with:
  #
  scope :user_replied_group_discussions, lambda {|user| replied_by(user) }

  private
    def self.replied_by(user)
      discussion_ids = %(SELECT commentable_id FROM comments 
                     WHERE commentable_type = 'Discussion' AND user_id = :user_id)
      where("discussable_type = 'Group' AND id IN (#{discussion_ids}) ", 
           { :user_id => user })
    end
end

# Table name: comments
#
#  id               :integer         not null, primary key
#  content          :text
#  created_at       :datetime
#  updated_at       :datetime
#  commentable_id   :integer
#  commentable_type :string(255)
#  user_id          :integer
#

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :commentable, :polymorphic => true
  belongs_to :user

end
```

---

**UPDATE:**
The sql query provided by @ypercube helped, I'm now using it with find_by_sql. But it seems awkward putting that in the controller.

**Is there a better solution? Thanks!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will order according to latest `discussions.updated_at` time:

```
where("discussable_type = 'Group' AND id IN (#{discussion_ids}) 
order by updated_at DESC ",
```

If you want to order by `comment.created_at`, use this query:

```
SELECT d.*
     , MAX(c.created_at) AS lastCommentTime
FROM discussions d
  JOIN comments c
    ON d.id = c.commentable_id
WHERE c.commentable_type = 'Discussion'
  AND c.user_id = userIDtoCheck
GROUP BY d.id
ORDER BY lastCommentTime DESC        <--- latest first
```

Comment: Thanks! that totally works! the problem is, i'm a rails newbie, i don't know how to use raw sql to replace the where() method. :(

Comment: @randomor: If your problem isn't solved, edit the question so it resurfaces in Questions list.

Comment: modifed! thanks for your great answer though, I'm now using it, but wondering if there is a better way.

Comment: @randomor: Check this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4122462/how-to-order-by-in-rails

Comment: @yercube: thanks, but that solution results in a double discussion problem if user posted two comments into the same discussion, which your query cleverly avoided by using the MAX function. I guess it is not possible to do that in rails code. I'll wait for another 24 hours for better solutions. :)